# Instagram API error code 400 “No matching code found”

Tags: php, api, instagram, instagram-api

```
$config = array(
                        'client_id' => '****',
                        'client_secret' => '****',
                        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
                        'redirect_uri' => 'https://example.com/order/',
                    'code' => $code,
                );
```

Since about 5-6 hours I'm getting this message when trying to authenticate:

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "No matching code found."}
```

Nothing has been change on the site and everything seems to be ok with the client. Does anyone have a clue about what may cause this?

Everything is working on our dev site, the only difference is that is uses an other client id. I have tried to create a new Instagram client and tested with the new client id, but no difference on the live site.

Comment: Is this a “fresh” code, that you acquired by sending the user through the login flow recently?

Comment: Yes, it's a fresh code generated at the moment of login. Everything worked fine last night, and when I checked this morning all users gets this when trying to login. @CBroe

Comment: I am sort of having the same problem. I ve tried changing the secret and API key and also creating a new client application but still does not work... Do you think it might have something to do with this: http://developers.instagram.com/post/116410697261/publishing-guidelines-and-signed-requests Anyway, according to that post, existing applications should still be working...

Comment: I don't think so. I have seen others post error messages like "Client disabled" that I think is related to problems caused by those things. The client id is still working for scenarios that not require authentication, so it's still active.

Do you get any other error message?

Comment: No, that is the only comment I receive. Like you say, the client still works for those users that already have a token created and stored, but it will not allow me to obtain new tokens. Users grant permissions, I receive the CODE back, but when I POST it to Instagram to obtain the token back, I get that error... Are you getting other messages apart from this one?

Comment: At the moment it seems like the reason might be that the servers IP have been blocked by Instagram. Moved the system to another server and now everything works fine again. I have contacted Instagram to get some feedback on that the reason may be and will continue investigating this on our side too. When I know anything further I'll post a more detailed answer here.

Comment: Another thing that might be related is that I recently modified the name of the app having troubles, and then set it back to its original name to see if it got fixed but with no results... did you change the name too?

Comment: Same for me: was working perfectly last night. Getting the same error as you now. I've tried changing reseting the secret, using a different account. Nothing helps. I'm behind a company firewall. Could be that high traffic from one IP has marked it is spam. Just guessing.

Comment: I am getting the same error when trying to authorize, as @Jonas said, since a few hours ago. I have no idea what could be the problem as using regular authorization, not through server, works. Also if I remove the Signed Headers options from settings, it POST calls work for already authorized users. Maybe they did something in the API that went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received an answer from Instagram today regarding this. Yet no information about the cause of the problem. But the problem is solved by them and in our case the old IP works again.

I have asked for some further details, so if I get any more information, I'll share it here.

Comment: What did they say exactly? I'm experiencing the same issue, can't get around the error message no matter what I try...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was initiating Instagram connection from page A and callback URL was different (Page B). Once I made sure that callback URL is the same from where I was initiating, this problem solved for me.